# Run-time Error '-2147467259 (80004005) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: oracle, excel, oracle11g, odbc, vba

I am trying to connect to oracle using excel macro. My connection string is as follows:

```
*"Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=edw))); uid=system; pwd=oracle;"*
```

[image: Configuered ODBC as shown in figure]

*OS : Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
MS Office Professional Plus 2013*

Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The driver does not exist, try `Driver={Oracle in OraDb11g_home1}`

However, ODBC exist for 32 bit and 64 bit. Which ODBC Data Source Administrator did you start (they look the same)?

To launch 64-bit ODBC Administrator use `%SystemRoot%\System32\odbcad32.exe`

To launch 32-bit ODBC Administrator use `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

The architecture of ODBC driver must match the architecture of your client, I assume this is MS Office which is most likely the 32 bit version.

ODBC driver for Oracle can be provided by Microsoft (`Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}`) or by Oracle (`Driver={Oracle in OraDb11g_home1}`, driver name varies). 64-bit driver is provided only by Oracle, the Microsoft driver is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

NB, I never used `CONNECTSTRING=...`, try `Server=...` instead.